# How do I get a file from S3 storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've got files up on Amazon S3 storage, now how do I download them?

Is there a simple url that I can use to get a protected file?

[this site](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#ConstructingTheAuthenticationHeader) suggests I use requests formatted like :

```
GET /photos/puppy.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: johnsmith.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: Mon, 26 Mar 2007 19:37:58 +0000
Authorization: AWS AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE:frJIUN8DYpKDtOLCwo//yllqDzg=
```

Does that translate to a url like  "johnsmith.s3.amazonaws.com/AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE:frJIUN8DYpKDtOLCwo//yllqDzg="?

The Authorization code before the `:` is the Access key, but the code after that, the "Signiature", is some encrypted proof that you have the secret key. How do you get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the permissions on the object are not public, and you want to grant access to someone temporarily through an HTTP request, you will probably to use query string authentication.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3_QSAuth.html

Note that there is a link at the end of that page pointing to information on signature generation.